# R rows to columns

Tags: r

Using R and dplyr, I have an aggregated dataframe with sentiment scores per day and per user:

```
date       | user | sentiment_score | anger | fear | trust
2016-12-15 | x    | -1              | 2     | 1    | 0
2016-12-16 | x    | -1              | 0     | 0    | 0
2016-12-15 | y    | 1               | 0     | 1    | 0
2016-12-16 | y    | -1              | 3     | 0    | 0
2016-12-15 | z    | 0               | 0     | 0    | 0
```

Dput:

```
df <- structure(list(created_at = structure(c(17150, 17151, 17150, 
17151, 17150), class = "Date"), user = c("x", "x", "y", "y", 
"z"), sentiment_score = c(-1, -1, 1, -1, 0), anger = c(2, 0, 
0, 3, 0), fear = c(1, 0, 1, 0, 0), trust = c(0, 0, 0, 0, 0)), .Names = c("created_at", 
"user", "sentiment_score", "anger", "fear", "trust"), class = "data.frame", row.names = c("1900961", 
"1900971", "1900981", "1900991", "1901001"))
```

For prediction purposes I would like to transform this dataframe to a dataframe per day with seperate sentiment score columns for each user (ending up with many columns):

```
date       | x_sentiment_score | x_anger | x_fear | x_trust| y_sentiment_score | y_anger | y_fear | y_trust| z_sentiment_score | z_anger | z_fear | z_trust
2016-12-15 | -1                | 2       | 1      | 0      | 1                 | 0       | 1      | 0      | 0                 | 0       | 0      | 0
2016-12-16 | -1                | 0       | 0      | 0      | -1                | 3       | 0      | 0      | 0                 | 0       | 0      | 0
```

I am puzzled how to achieve this. Any advice would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: you should get a `dput`at least so that people can work with your data,

Comment: sorry, I have included the `dput`

Comment: please go through the answers in the link shared by @Cath.. it helps! explore `dcast()` from data.table package

Comment: Thank you, will do!